# NSDictionary method allKeys crashes after JSON Serialization in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a dictionary instance declared in `PageOneView.h`:

```
@interface PageOneView : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, 
                                           UITableViewDelegate, 
                                           UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *orderDetailsDictionary ;
}
@property  (nonatomic, retain )NSDictionary *orderDetailsDictionary;
```

I synthesize it in `PageOneView.m`:

```
@implementation PageOneView

@synthesize orderDetailsDictionary;
```

I initialize it with an object returned by `JSONSerialization` class. (`orderDetailsJSON` is a JSON string I have read from a web service) This line is borrowed from the Apple sample code:

```
orderDetailsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
[orderDetailsJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

Next I try to get the first key.

```
NSString *valString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
           @"%@\n", [[orderDetailsDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

`allKeys` crashes here with `Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. the output screen shows:

```
-[__NSCFArray allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a211d0
```

Comment: You are getting an array not a dictionary from your Json parser. NSArray does not respond to allKeys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, `orderDetailsDictionary` is not a `NSDictionary`, but a `NSArray`. You should check the data coming from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
orderDetailsDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[yourArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *valString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@\n", [orderDetailsDictionary objectForKey:0]];
```